# Google Cloud Functions CPU Speed Setup

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I was not able to find settings for GCF to setup CPU speed. In pricing calculator there is several options for GCF environment on which it running, and by default as I understand the least performant option is used (800MHz?). So, I wounder, is there any options in Cloud Console or during Functions deploy to setup CPU speed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The memory size and CPU speed are connected.  The details are on the pricing page:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing

So, if you allocate 1024MB of memory to your function, you'll get a 1.4GHz CPU.