# google cloud functions cpu speed from command line

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

How do I set the CPU speed with `gcloud functions deploy`? When I run the following

```
gcloud functions deploy "$FUNC" \
       --gen2 \
       --runtime=python310 \
       --region=us-central1 \
       --source=. \
       --entry-point="$ENTRY" \
       --trigger-http \
       --allow-unauthenticated \
       --memory=128MiB \
       --min-instances=1
```

I end up with a function with 128MB and 0.583 CPU. I suspect 0.583 comes from an old setting when I set the memory to 1024MB. I don't see an argument for the CPU and changing it using the GCP UI is not ideal.

[Google Cloud Functions CPU Speed Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406121/google-cloud-functions-cpu-speed-setup) suggests that memory and cpu are tied but that doesn't seem to be the case.

EDIT: I filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259575942

Comment: I am not sure but I think for gen2 you must delete the function and then redeploy it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @John Hanley, you have to delete the function and redeploy in order to change the memory.

I tried to replicate the issue at my end and I noticed that I wasn't able to increase the memory beyond 512MB. I have to create a new function to change memory.

And also noticed that we cannot increase the memory beyond specified memory at time of deploying functions. I.e if you deploy a function with `--memory=1GiB`, you can’t increase it to 2GiB.

It seems like there is a bug in Cloud Function gen2, if this bug affects your production. Please raise a bug in [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) with description or contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/contact)